# Regex is not capturing the src from a unique img id

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

In my WordPress v5.7, I have a form to show a book image from another e-commerce portal selling books. User will enter the book selling page URL of an e-coomerce portal in the form, below code is expected to find the src from the `<img id="bookImage" src="....">`, in the `<img>` tag `id="bookImage"` is the unique identifier.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['bookURL'])) {
    $bookURL = 'https://www.example.com/book/.....';
    echo getBookTitle($bookURL);
    echo '<img src="' . getBookImageURL($bookURL) . '">';
}

// BOOK TITLE
function getBookTitle($url) {
    $aurl = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match('~<span id="bookTitle"[^>]*>(.*?)</span>~si', $aurl, $title);
    $bookTitle = $title[0];
    return $bookTitle;
}

// BOOK IMAGE URL
function getBookImageURL($url) {
    $aurl = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match('/<img[^>]*id="bookImage"[^>]*src="([^"]+)">/', $aurl, $imgURL);
    $bookImageURL = $imgURL[0];
    return $bookImageURL;
}
```

With the above code, I am able to get the book title, but not the book image src.

Comment: Can you share `$aurl` ?

Comment: This url is from Google Reads "https://books.google.ae/books?id=SeGMDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=hit+refresh&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5_qrR0s3vAhXHa8AKHT7oCEsQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=hit%20refresh&f=false"

If google reads, the `<img>` unique identifier will be `id="summary-frontcover"`.

Comment: Can you try `<img[^>]*(?|id="bookImage"[^>]*src="([^"]+)|src="([^"]+)"[^>]*id="bookImage")[^>]*>` https://regex101.com/r/0xymXy/1 Maybe the attributes are in another order, or there are more attributes after it before matching the closing `>`

Comment: It retrieves the complete `<img>` tag, I just need the URL from the `src=""` from the `<img>` tag.

Comment: @theKing You can get capture group 1 to get that value. I have added an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you use a pattern with a capture group, which means the booktitle itself is in `$title[1]` and the same for the image src `$imgURL[1]`. Using `[0]` as the index will return the full match.

One option could be using `[^>]*>` at the end of the pattern, incase there is more after the attribute.

If there can be a different order, you might use a branch reset group `(?|` to match either one of the order, and still use group 1 to get the value.

```
<img[^>]*(?|id="bookImage"[^>]+src="([^"]+)"|src="([^"]+)"[^>]+id="bookImage")[^>]*>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t2BObH/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/nqo0t)

For example

```
$s = '<img id="bookImage" src="test.jpg">';
preg_match('/<img[^>]*(?|id="bookImage"[^>]+src="([^"]+)"|src="([^"]+)"[^>]+id="bookImage")[^>]*>/', $s, $imgURL);
var_dump($imgURL[1]);
```

Output

```
string(8) "test.jpg"
```

**Note** that you might be better of using [DOMDocument::getElementById](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) as you already know `id="bookTitle"` and `id="bookImage"`.

For example

```
$s = '<span id="bookTitle">book title</span>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($s);
$bookTitle = $dom->getElementById("bookTitle")->nodeValue;
var_dump($bookTitle);


$s = '<img id="bookImage" src="test.jpg">';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($s);
$imgSrc = $dom->getElementById("bookImage")->getAttribute("src");
var_dump($imgSrc);
```

Output

```
string(10) "book title"
string(8) "test.jpg"
```

Comment: Good to suggest DOMDocument ;)

Comment: @theKing I have added an example to use capture group 1, see https://3v4l.org/B54FF

Comment: @theKing If you don't want to use a capture group, you can use lookarounds to get a match only `<img[^>]*(?|id="bookImage"[^>]+src="\K[^"]+(?="[^>]*>)|src="\K[^"]+(?="[^>]+id="bookImage"[^>]*>))` See https://regex101.com/r/0tjA45/1